# Draw segment 1/4th below the top of a canvas using paper.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

For a portfolio site I am creating, I want to draw a line in Paper.js one-quarter from the top of the target canvas, to make a header of sorts.  I tried this code using the `view` functionality but don't see anything:

```js
var ycoord = view.size.height * 0.25;
var xcoord = view.size.width;
console.log(pos);
var point3 = new Point(xcoord, ycoord);
var point4 = new Point(xcoord, 0);
var pathh = new Path({
  segments: [point3, point4],
  strokeColor: 'black',
  strokeWidth: '10',
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused x and y and you are actually drawing a vertical line at the right of the screen.
Here is the corrected code:

```
var ycoord = view.size.height * 0.25;
var xcoord = view.size.width;
var point3 = new Point(0, ycoord);
var point4 = new Point(xcoord, ycoord);
var pathh = new Path({
    segments: [point3, point4],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: '10',
});
```